# Returning a function signature based on generic parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typescript1.8, typescript-generics

I have a function `createRequest`:

```js
function createRequest(method: string, path: string) {
  return function resourceApiCall() {
    // ...additional logic
    return httpCall(path, method) 
  }
}
```

that returns a function `resourceApiCall` that I would like to call like:

```js
const fetchUsers = createRequest('GET', '/users')

await fetchUsers({createdAfter: new Date()})
```

I would also like to do something like:

```js
const fetchPayment = createRequest('GET', '/payments')

await fetchPayment('id', {createdAfter: new Date()})
```

**My question is, how can I pass a definition to `createRequest` so that `fetchUsers` and `fetchPayment` display the correct function parameters and return value inside the IDE (any type-check correctly)?**

I believe I need to do something like:

```js
interface FetchPayment {
  (id: string, {createdAfter: Date}): Promise<{id: string}>
}

const fetchPayment = createRequest<FetchPayment>('GET', '/payments')
```

but I would ideally like to do something like:

```js
const fetchPayment = createRequest<Args, Result>('GET', '/payments')

function createRequest<Args, Result>(method: string, path: string) {
  return function resourceApiCall(...args: Args) {
    // ...additional logic
    return httpCall<Result>(path, method) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might proceed like this:

```
// some interfaces you expect httpCall to return
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
interface Payment {
  id: string;
}

// a mapping of request paths to the function signatures
// you expect to return from createRequest
interface Requests {
  "/users": (clause: { createdAfter: Date }) => Promise<Array<User>>;
  "/payments": (id: string, clause: { createdAfter: Date }) => Promise<Payment>;
}

// a dummy httpCall function
declare function httpCall<R>(path: string, method: string, payload: any): R;

// for now only GET is supported, and the path must be one of keyof Requests
function createRequest<P extends keyof Requests>(method: "GET", path: P) {
  return (function resourceApiCall(
    ...args: Parameters<Requests[P]> // Parameters<F> is the arg tuple of function type F
  ): ReturnType<Requests[P]> { // ReturnType<F> is the return type of function type F
    return httpCall<ReturnType<Requests[P]>>(path, method, args);
  } as any) as Requests[P]; // assertion to clean up createRequest signature
}

async function foo() {
  const fetchUsers = createRequest("GET", "/users");
  const users = await fetchUsers({ createdAfter: new Date() }); // User[]
  const fetchPayment = createRequest("GET", "/payments");
  const payment = await fetchPayment("id", { createdAfter: new Date() }); // Payment
}
```

In the above I'm using an interface `Requests` to specify at the type level the mapping from the request path to the function signature you want `createRequest()` to return.  And `createRequest()` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function using using `Requests` to strongly type the returned function.  Notice that inside the implementation of `resourceApiCall()` I also use some built-in [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to pull the [argument types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.4.5/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1471-L1474) and [return type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.4.5/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1481-L1484) out of a function signature.  This is not strictly necessary, but makes the typings inside of `resourceApiCall()` more explicit.

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

---

UPDATE: Here's a possible way to split that up into different modules so that each module only touches its own endpoint.

First, have your file with `createRequest()` in it, along with an initially empty `Requests` interface:

**Requests/requests.ts**

```
export interface Requests extends Record<keyof Requests, (...args: any[]) => any> {
  // empty here, but merge into this 
}

// a dummy httpCall function
declare function httpCall<R>(path: string, method: string, payload: any): R;

// for now only GET is supported, and the path must be one of keyof Requests
export function createRequest<P extends keyof Requests>(method: "GET", path: P) {
  return (function resourceApiCall(
    ...args: Parameters<Requests[P]> // Parameters<F> is the arg tuple of function type F
  ): ReturnType<Requests[P]> {
    // ReturnType<F> is the return type of function type F
    return httpCall<ReturnType<Requests[P]>>(path, method, args);
  } as any) as Requests[P]; // assertion to clean up createRequest signature
}
```

Then you can make a module for your `User` stuff:

**Requests/user.ts**

```
export interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
declare module './requests' {
  interface Requests {
    "/users": (clause: { createdAfter: Date }) => Promise<Array<User>>;
  }
}
```

and your `Payment` stuff:

**Requests/payment.ts**

```
export interface Payment {
  id: string;
}
declare module './requests' {
  interface Requests {
    "/payments": (id: string, clause: { createdAfter: Date }) => Promise<Payment>;
  }
}
```

et cetera.  Finally a user could call these by importing `createRequest` and possibly the `user` and `payment` modules (if they have code in them you need to run in your module):

**test.ts**

```
import { createRequest } from './Requests/requests';
import './Requests/user'; // maybe not necessary
import './Requests/payment'; // maybe not necessary

async function foo() {
  const fetchUsers = createRequest("GET", "/users");
  const users = await fetchUsers({ createdAfter: new Date() }); // User[]
  const fetchPayment = createRequest("GET", "/payments");
  const payment = await fetchPayment("id", { createdAfter: new Date() }); // Payment
}
```

Okay, hope that helps again.

Comment: This is a great help @jcalz! Is there a way you can think of where I can declare the expected args and return type inline instead of using the `interface Requests`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... you can use a type alias instead (`type Requests = { "/users": (clause: { createdAfter: Date }) => Promise<Array<User>>; ...`) but you probably want to have *some* name for it, since `Requests` shows up multiple times in the signature and the implementation, and writing that type over and over again could be annoying.  If I understood your use case more I might be able to make a suggestion.  Why don't you want a `Requests` interface or type?

Comment: I would like to co-locate the individual type definitions because I'm creating an internal client sdk (an abstraction of http calls).  I'm following the patterns that most large scale companies use, most specifically stripe's.  In this example https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/lib/resources/Charges.js, they have a `Charges` resource that simply creates an endpoint.  I would like mine to look exactly like that + inline the expected args and return value of the endpoint.  My `createRequest` is the equivalent of Stripe's `stripeMethod`.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: So can I suggest keeping the `Requests` interface and using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add endpoints into `Requests`?  Let me see if I can refactor the code above to demonstrate that...

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps more.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine aliases and overloads to get this working. Basically alias those arguments as string literal types, and then give your function multiple signatures. TypeScript can then infer the return type of `createRequest` based on the arguments passed in

```
type UserPath = '/users';
type PaymentPath = '/payment';
type CreatedAfter = {
  createdAfter: Date;
};

function createRequest(
  HttpVerb: string,
  target: UserPath
): (id: string, date: CreatedAfter) => Promise<{ id: string }>;

function createRequest(
  HttpVerb: string,
  target: PaymentPath
  //I'm just guessing the return type here
): (date: CreatedAfter) => Promise<{ id: string }[]>; 

function createRequest(HttpVerb: string, target: UserPath | PaymentPath): any {
  //your function implementation doesn't have to be like this, this is just so
  //this example is fully working
  if (target === '/users') {
    return async function(date) {
      return { id: '1' };
    };
  } else if (target === '/payment') {
    return async function(id, date) {
      return [{ id: '1' }];
    };
  }
}

//this signature matches your fetchUsers signature
const fetchUsers = createRequest('GET', '/users'); 

//this signature matches your fetchPayment signature
const fetchPayment = createRequest('GET', '/payment');
```

In summation, this will allow the `createRequest` function to return a function with the correct signature based on the second argument passed. [Read more about function signatures here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html), ctrl+f and search for "Overloads" to learn more about overloading.